# Select * from table with NodeJS // ERROR: { error: relation "mytable" does not exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, select, search-path

I get the following error during my SELECT query from PostgreSQL DB

```
ERROR: { error: relation "free_subnets" does not exist
    at Connection.parseE (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:604:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:401:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  name: 'error',
  length: 103,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '15',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_relation.c',
  line: '874',
  routine: 'parserOpenTable' }
```

If I use psql command and do a select there, it works.

\dt provides me the relation:

```
   Schema    |     Name     | Type  |  Owner   
-------------+--------------+-------+----------
 subnet_calc | free_subnets | table | postgres
```

Search_path has been set to: subnet_calc, public

I've created the table with user postgres, so I am the owner of the schema subnet_calc and the table free_subnets.

My dummy nodejs code is the following:

```js
const pg = require('pg');


const cs = 'postgres://postgres:password@anydb.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/subnet_calculator';

const client = new pg.Client(cs);
client.connect();

client.query('SELECT * FROM subnet_calc.free_subnets', function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

What could be the issue?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshots if the content is just text. Copy/paste it, so it's easier to search for and examine.

Comment: Please post text, not links of images to text. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Hi VLAZ and Dave Newton, I've added texts instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve the issue. It was my failure, the tables were created in DB postgres not in subnet_calculator.

I will close this question.

Comment: Its a bit sad and funny but a valid reason. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you need to set search path for it like this:

```
db.query("SET search_path TO 'subnet_calc';")
```

and then do the query :

```
const query = `SELECT * FROM free_subnets`

db.query(query)
```

Comment: Hi Raj,Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, it does not work. Actually, SEARCH_PATH was already set to that.

Comment: how did you set the search path? What i'm suggesting is try setting it separately and then run the query. See what results you get.

Comment: ```
const pg = require('pg');
const cs = 'postgres://postgres:password@anyhost:5432/anydb';
const client = new pg.Client(cs);
client.connect();
client.query("SET search_path TO 'subnet_calc';")
client
  .query('SELECT * from free_subnets;')
  .then(res => console.log(res.rows[0]))
  .catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
```
I don't get your point. I've tried it and with the above mentioned code and it does not work.